# Help with GROUP BY clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

need your help with `GROUP BY` clause.

I have two tables: **Managers** and **Clients** (I simplified it for a question).

```
Managers:
managerId int PK,
ManagerName nvarchar(50)
```

and

```
Clients:
ClientId int,
ClientName nvarchar(50),
ManagerId int, WhenAdded datetime
```

I store managers list in Managers table. Each client from Clients table has a corresponding manager.

I want a sql query which returns following table:

```
ManagerName nvarchar(50),
NumberOfClients int
```

My problem is:
if manager doesn't have a client(s). Sql query doesn't include `ManagerName` in resulting table.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT M.ManagerName, COUNT(*) 
FROM
Clients AS C left join Managers AS M 
ON
C.ManagerId = M.ManagerId
GROUP BY 
M.ManagerName
```

**Second question**

Same as a first question, but if I want to add a `where` clause to the `WhenAdded` field in Clients). Query must return `ManagerName` and `NumberOfClients` even if `NumberOfClients=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT ManagerName, (SELECT Count(ClientID) FROM Clients C WHERE
    C.ManagerID=M.ManagerID) As NumberOfClients FROM Managers M;
```

or this:

```
SELECT ManagerName, Count(C.ClientID) As NumberOfClients FROM Managers M
    LEFT JOIN Clients C ON M.ManagerID=C.ManagerID GROUP BY M.ManagerID,
    M.ManagerName;
```

The problem with your query is that you're using Clients table as basic table.

For the second question you can use this:

```
SELECT ManagerName, (SELECT Count(ClientID) FROM Clients C WHERE
    WhenAdded<DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) AND M.ManagerID=C.ManagerID) As
    NumberOfClients FROM Managers M;
```

Comment: Second query solve my problem. Thanks. How do I add a having clause (using WhenAdded) if I want to get a table with same columns (ManagerId, NumberOfClients) ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Not very optimized though!

```
select m.ManagerName , count(c.ManagerId) from Managers m, Clients c where 
m.ManagerId = c.ManagerId group by c.ManagerId
```